# how to deploy kuali CM in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, kuali

I've been installing the kuali curriculum management system by following the quickstart guide given [HERE](https://wiki.kuali.org/display/STUDENTDOC/KS+Curriculum+Management+2.0+QuickStart+Installation+Guide).

I've successfully done everything but I'm unable to deploy the application in tomcat.

I've never really used tomcat before so can anybody please tell me how to follow the given steps. Like where do I add the memory settings and what is the oracle jar file etc.

1. Add the following memory settings to your server configuration
   -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m
2. Add the Oracle JAR to your Tomcat server's classpath (typically done by copying the JAR in TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory).
3. Copy the WAR file into TOMCAT_HOME/webapps (it is recommended that the version number be removed from the war filename before copying).
4. Start Tomcat

Comment: you need to install oracle database in your pc..then download [ojdbc14.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html)  and put in your tomcat installation lib folder(just copy paste) - Tomcat7/lib..copy war file and paste Tomcat7/Webapps..start tomcat just run statup.bat in Tomcat7/bin folder

Comment: Thanks, and can you please tell me how to set the server configuration, step no. 1.

Comment: use this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/)..

Answer (score 1):

The "Oracle JAR" is a JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) driver [available from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). It does not come bundled with Kuali software because its terms of use do not allow redistribution.

For where to put the memory settings, see the [documentation on running Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt), particularly section *(3.4) Using the "setenv" script*. What you put in there depends on your OS.

Windows (bin/setenv.bat):

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m
```

*nix (bin/setenv.sh):

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m"
```

After the files are in place, run

Windows:

```
bin\catalina.bat run
```

*nix:

```
bin/catalina.sh run
```